# NuGet - is it possible to exclude downloading libraries not targeting project's .NET version

Tags: .net, nuget

When I install nuget package the manager downloads libraries for all available .NET versions (2.0, 3.5, 4.0). Is there a way for me to automatically exclude libraries for .NET versions which are not targeting the project I am installing into?

Comment: The current NuGet design requires it to download the package, decompress and then see if a suitable assembly can be found for your project. I think in this case there is no way to achieve what you wanted.

Comment: I was afraid of that. The problem with this is that I keep getting lots of binaries (that's quite a lot of MBs in some cases) and by default they get added to repository. I prefer to remove those unwatned binaries and I will need to do it manually. But still NuGet could delete unnecessary binaries after it does the check. Sounds like a possible improvement?

Comment: There is package restore, so why do you check in those packages to repo?

Comment: Good point, package restore is best in my case. Thanks. I would accept if this was an answer.

Comment: @andy250: Lex Li's comment is a solution to your problem, but I'd argue it shouldn't be an answer, because it doesn't answer the question you are asking here.